# Getting Render error when calling function from Alert.alert in react native

Tags: react-native, error-handling, event-listener

When i am calling the function after countdown time finish from the alert its showing error like below i have mentioned

```
 ERROR  TypeError: _reactNative.AppState.removeEventListener is not a function (it is undefined)
```

I have used the backhandler form handle back in like below

```
 useFocusEffect(
    useCallback(() => {
      const handleBackPress = () => {
        Alert.alert('Computer Course', 'Are you sure to close app ?', [
          {
            text: 'Yes',
            style: 'default',
            onPress: submitExam(),
          },
        ]);
        return true;
      };
      const back = BackHandler.addEventListener(
        'hardwareBackPress',
        handleBackPress,
      );
      return () => {
        back.remove();
      };
    }, []),
  );
```

And i am using the countdown library for timer and calling the alert after finish like below

```
 <CountDown
  onFinish={() => handleModelView()}
/>
```

and here is one more aler for calling submitExam()

```
  const handleModelView = () => {
    console.log('here is coming');
    Alert.alert('Computer Course', 'Are you sure to close app ?', [
      {
        text: 'Yes',
        style: 'default',
        onPress: () => {
          submitExam();
        },
      },
    ]);
  };
```